# Race conditions in my signal handlers? (C)

Tags: c, shell, system, signals, race-condition

I'm working on a shell lab for a Systems course, and I've been having some really weird race condition bugs that I've been trying to solve since Friday night and can't seem to pin down.

My current code: http://buu700.com/tsh

Everything before `START OF MY CODE` and after `END OF MY CODE` is provided by the course instructors, so none of that should be the source of the issues.

We have a test script as well; here is the output of my current test results: http://buu700.com/sdriver

---

```
/*****************
 * Signal handlers
 *****************/

/* 
 * sigchld_handler - The kernel sends a SIGCHLD to the shell whenever
 *     a child job terminates (becomes a zombie), or stops because it
 *     received a SIGSTOP, SIGTSTP, SIGTTIN or SIGTTOU signal. The 
 *     handler reaps all available zombie children, but doesn't wait 
 *     for any other currently running children to terminate.  
 */
void 
sigchld_handler(int sig) 
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status, termsig;
    struct job_t *job;


    sigset_t s;

    sigemptyset(&s);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGCHLD);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGTSTP);

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &s, NULL);


    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED)) > 0) {
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            deletejob(job_list, pid);
        }
        if ((termsig = WTERMSIG(status))) {
            deletejob(job_list, pid);
            safe_printf("Job [%i] (%i) %s by signal %i\n",
                            pid2jid(pid), pid, "terminated", termsig);
        }
        if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            job = getjobpid(job_list, pid);
            job->state = ST;
            safe_printf("Job [%i] (%i) %s by signal %i\n",
                            pid2jid(pid), pid, "stopped", SIGTSTP);
        }
    }

    if (errno != ECHILD)
        unix_error("waitpid error");

    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &s, NULL);

    return;
}



/* 
 * sigint_handler - The kernel sends a SIGINT to the shell whenver the
 *    user types ctrl-c at the keyboard.  Catch it and send it along
 *    to the foreground job.  
 */
void 
sigint_handler(int sig) 
{
    sigset_t s;

    sigemptyset(&s);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGCHLD);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGTSTP);

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &s, NULL);

    kill(-1, sig);

    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &s, NULL);

    return;
}



/*
 * sigtstp_handler - The kernel sends a SIGTSTP to the shell whenever
 *     the user types ctrl-z at the keyboard. Catch it and suspend the
 *     foreground job by sending it a SIGTSTP.  
 */
void 
sigtstp_handler(int sig) 
{
    sigset_t s;

    sigemptyset(&s);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGCHLD);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGTSTP);

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &s, NULL);

    kill(-1, sig);

    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &s, NULL);

    return;
}
```

Comment: I find your faith in professor-supplied code _adorable_. :)

Comment: Haha, it looks like pretty solid code to me, and most students have already finished the lab so clearly the course-provided code works. (As far as I know, though, none of it was actually personally written by either of my professors.)

Comment: Can you please give a better description of the fault. And explain why you think it is a race condition?

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion that the bug comes from your racing against other signals in your signal handlers:

```
sigint_handler(int sig) 
{
    sigset_t s;

    sigemptyset(&s);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGCHLD);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGTSTP);

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &s, NULL);
```

When you register the signal handler with `sigaction(2)`, you can provide an `sa_mask` that the kernel will use to block signals for you while your signal handler is running. This is done atomically and requires no extra work on your part. Simply populate this mask once when registering the signal handler.

Another possibility comes from the `SIGTSTP` signal; page 350 of my copy of [APUE, 2nd edition](http://www.apuebook.com/) says, in part:

> Only a job-control shell should reset the disposition of [`SIGTSTP`, `SIGTTIN`, `SIGTTOU`] to `SIG_DFL`.

What's left unsaid in those paragraphs, but I think is fair to assume, is that the shell should set the signal disposition to `SIG_DFL` for the *child processes* -- it still needs to do something to handle the signals itself.

Did you properly handle the signal dispositions in the children?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The course-provided code actually has a wrapper around sigaction which handles the blocking the way you described; I actually just threw that in the handlers as one of those random senseless things one tends to hack around with while aimlessly debugging (it didn't affect the tester output at all). I'll remove it now since it's definitely not correct.

---

I also did something like what you're suggesting with SIG_DFL while I was debugging; does this look anywhere close to correct? http://buu700.com/runcommand

Comment: Something that scared me right away was this: `sprintf(cmd, "%s%s ", cmd, argv[i]);`. Note the warning in `sprintf(3)`: _C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call to `sprintf()`, `snprintf()`, `vsprintf()`, or `vsnprintf()` would cause copying to take place between objects that overlap (e.g., if the target string array and one of the supplied input arguments refer to the same buffer)._

Comment: Thanks, just fixed that (it felt dangerous when I wrote it). I'm still getting the same output from the test script, but that part should be better now.